# Why will the python matplotlib graph not show?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, matplotlib, graph

For some reason I cannot get a matplotlib graph to show. When I run the code, it doesn't output anything and it shouldn't, only the graph should be displayed, but its not. Any help will be much appreciated. 
I'm trying to get the graph to fetch info from the database, but unfortunately no luck.

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import style
style.use('bmh')

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot(unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')

def data_entry():
        c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(1451255552, '2020-02-18', 'Python', 8)")
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()

def dynamic_data_entry():
    unix = time.time()
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    keyword = 'Python'
    value = random.randrange(0,10)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot (unix, datestamp, keyword, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (unix, date, keyword, value))
    conn.commit()

def read_from_db():
    c.execute("SELECT keyword, unix FROM stuffToPlot WHERE unix > 1452618731")
    #data = c.fetchall()
    #print(data)
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row)

def graph_data():
    c.execute('SELECT unix, value FROM stuffToPlot')
    dates = []
    values = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        #print(row[0])
        #print(datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]))
        dates.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]))
        values.append(row[1])
    plt.plot_date(dates, values, '-')
    plt.show()


##create_table()
###data_entry()
##for i in range(10):
##    dynamic_data_entry()
##    time.sleep(1)
##read_from_db()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: You aren't calling any functions. Just connected to the database and then closing the connection

Answer (score 0):

```
graph_data()
```

should solve the issue.

======

Edited. This tutorial has many mistakes. After some editions:

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import style
style.use('bmh')

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot(unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')

def data_entry():
        c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(1451255552, '2020-02-18', 'Python', 8)")
        conn.commit()

def dynamic_data_entry():
    unix = time.time()
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    keyword = 'Python'
    value = random.randrange(0,10)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot (unix, datestamp, keyword, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (unix, date, keyword, value))
    conn.commit()

def read_from_db():
    c.execute("SELECT keyword, unix FROM stuffToPlot WHERE unix > 1452618731")
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print(row)

def graph_data():
    c.execute('SELECT unix, value FROM stuffToPlot')
    dates = []
    values = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        dates.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row[0]))
        values.append(row[1])
    plt.plot_date(dates, values, '-')
    plt.show()


create_table()

for i in range(10):
    dynamic_data_entry()
    time.sleep(1)
read_from_db()
graph_data()
```

And the output is following:

[image]

The issue was here that data_entry function inserts an outlier that contaminated the graph (all other dates was inserted with today's date).

Comment: unfortunately it gave me invalid syntax

Comment: there is no error trace, just has highlited from graph_data() in red and an invalid syntax message

Comment: Cannot be in Python. This is valid syntax. Have you write it from the beginning of the line?

Comment: im trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq4nwICEB4U&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDezJh0sC5CqXLKZTSKU1YNo&index=4

Comment: Don't follow this tutorial. It has more and more mistakes.

Comment: It does not. He copy pasted this code. For example entry_data function closes the connection to database. So the next function fro the original tutorial cannot work.

Comment: https://pythonprogramming.net/graphing-from-sqlite-database/  He put the code here and its different, but even if I run the code that he put on the website, it still doesnt work for some reason